# Initializing a FnMut member variable with a static Fn function

Tags: rust

## Problem Description

I have a `Config` struct that can store a `FnMut` callback function. The catch is: not all of my configurations require a callback function, so I would like to make adding a callback function optional. This requires the member variable to be initialized with a default function that will get used if no callback is set.

## Existing Code

```rust
struct Config<'a>{
    callback: &'a mut dyn (FnMut(&str))
}

fn default_fn(msg: &str){
    println!("default_fn({})", msg);
}

impl<'a> Config<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Config<'a> {
        Config{
            callback: &default_fn // ERROR: types differ in mutability
        }
    }
    
    pub fn set_callback(mut self, callback_fn: &'a mut dyn (FnMut(&str))) -> Config<'a> {
        self.callback = callback_fn;
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Our FnMut callback
    let mut msg_log: Vec<String> = vec![];
    let mut callback_fn = |msg: &str| {
        msg_log.push(msg.to_string());
    };
    
    {
        let mut config = Config::new();
        (config.callback)("Hello World!");
        
        config = config.set_callback(&mut callback_fn);
        (config.callback)("Hello World!");
    }
    
    // Demonstration that the callback actually works
    println!("{:?}", msg_log);
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:13:23
   |
13 |             callback: &default_fn // ERROR: types differ in mutability
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^ types differ in mutability
   |
   = note: expected type `&mut dyn for<'r> std::ops::FnMut(&'r str)`
              found type `&for<'r> fn(&'r str) {default_fn}`
```

Does someone have any suggestions on how to solve that problem?

Things I already tried, without any success:

- Initializing it with a closure: `callback: &|_: &str|{}`
- Using a member function instead of a global function
- Creating a mutable reference: `callback: &mut default_fn`
  (causes: `cannot return value referencing temporary value`)

I'm running out of ideas, any help is appreciated. Even if the answer is that what I am trying to do is impossible for reasons I didn't realize yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really box the trait object function. That makes the whole code much easier to use:

```
struct Config<'a>{
    callback: Box<dyn FnMut(&str) + 'a>,
}

fn default_fn(msg: &str){
    println!("default_fn({})", msg);
}

impl<'a> Config<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Config<'a> {
        Config{
            callback: Box::new(default_fn)
        }
    }

    pub fn set_callback(self, callback: &'a mut dyn (FnMut(&str))) -> Config<'a> {
        Config {
            callback: Box::new(callback),
            ..self
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Our FnMut callback
    let mut msg_log = vec![];
    let mut callback_fn = |msg: &str| {
        msg_log.push(msg.to_string());
    };

    {
        let mut config = Config::new();
        (config.callback)("Hello World!");

        config = config.set_callback(&mut callback_fn);
        (config.callback)("Hello World!");
    }

    // Demonstration that the callback actually works
    println!("{:?}", msg_log);
}
```

---

Note that it is difficult to use callbacks in idiomatic Rust. I would even say that they aren't idiomatic at all. You should use a [channel](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html), something like that:

```
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Sender, SendError};

struct Config {
    sender: Sender<String>,
}

impl Config {
    pub fn new(sender: Sender<String>) -> Config {
        Config{
            sender
        }
    }

    pub fn send(&self, message: String) -> Result<(), SendError<String>> {
        self.sender.send(message)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let (sender, receiver) = channel();

    let config = Config::new(sender);
    config.send("Hello world!".into()).unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", receiver.recv().unwrap());
}
```

Comment: The most important point in this answer is that callback based designs aren't suitable to Rust. Just don't try to apply those patterns to Rust.

Comment: If callback based designs aren't suitable for rust, what do I use instead? In my case, this is a puzzle solver, and every time the solver finds a solution, it should call a user-defined function that tells him that it found a solution. I think channels are a good idea, but that would force the program to become multi-threaded. Are there similar single-threaded solutions?

Comment: @Finomnis I've added an example. Channel and multi-threaded code are totally uncorrelated.

Comment: Also, I disagree that `Rc` is necessary, that was a mistake in my code. I edited my question, added a new scope, so that the `Rc` and `RefCell` isn't necessary any more.

Comment: @Finomnis Honestly, don't use callbacks. Channels are much more easier to reason about, and you don't need to fight the borrow-checker.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199367/discussion-between-french-boiethios-and-finomnis).

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to share the solution I found:
Single-threaded, callback-based.

While in my opinion this one really answers the question I had, I think you guys are still right about the problems I might encounter in the future with this programming style. I will definitely reconsider your advice about using channels.

```
struct Config<'a>{
    callback: Option<&'a mut dyn (FnMut(&str))>
}

impl<'a> Config<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Config<'a> {
        Config{
            callback: None
        }
    }

    pub fn set_callback(mut self, callback_fn: &'a mut dyn (FnMut(&str))) -> Config<'a> {
        self.callback = Some(callback_fn);
        self
    }

    pub fn run_callback(&mut self, msg: &str){
        if let Some(callback) = &mut self.callback{
            callback(msg);
        } else {
            // Default code
            println!("default_fn({})", msg);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Our FnMut callback
    let mut msg_log: Vec<String> = vec![];
    let mut callback_fn = |msg: &str| {
        msg_log.push(msg.to_string());
    };

    let mut config = Config::new();
    config.run_callback("Hello World!");

    config = config.set_callback(&mut callback_fn);
    config.run_callback("Hello World!");

    // Demonstration that the callback actually works
    println!("{:?}", msg_log);
}
```